# Angular-Material set a Datepicker to only date in Angular7

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular-7 for web portal application. I have a Material Datepicker from which I would like to only get date with no timestamp. Also it should be in this format: dd/mm/yyyy

This is how it appears on the frontend:

[image: datepicker]

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <label for="loading_date">Loading Date</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker] = "picker" placeholder = "Choose a date" name="loading_date" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.loading_date" #loading_date="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : loading_date.invalid && ((loading_date.dirty || loading_date.touched) || quoteform.submitted)}"   required>
     <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for] = "picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
     <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
  <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="loading_date.invalid && ((loading_date.dirty || loading_date.touched) || quoteform.submitted)">
  <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="loading_date.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Loading Date is required.</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I When I submit into the database, I want to get a result in this format:

> 2019-09-26

But this is what I am getting:

> 2019-09-26T23:00:00.000Z

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `moment` to acheive thi;

```
npm i moment --save
```

Try this

```
var dateToDB = moment(loading_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Or you can use DatePipe

```
@Injectable()
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
class MyService {

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    var dateToDBthis.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); 
  }
}
```

In your app.module.ts

```
providers: [DatePipe,...]
```

Comment: Please be aware that moment.js in not recommended for new projects see [moment.js project status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) for more information.

Comment: @Tom Angular Material recommends the use of moment and its adapter to use datepicker with locals